# select elements outsde of plugin chaining this keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi im creating a plugin with chaining the problem is I want to select elements outside of the THIS element e.g

```
return $this.each(function() {
    $('body $left .filter-wrapper input[type=checkbox]', document).change(function() {
        alert('changed');// I want to break out side the scope how do i do that
        and select element that aren't in $('mygrid').Grid()
        // ive tried $('body $left .filter-wrapper input[type=checkbox]') 
        // that doesn't work either
    }).find(this).filter(....).click(function() {
        // this refers to mygrid which is what i want but the ubove code doen't work 
    }).find(....).click(function(){
        // do more stuff here
    }).bind('....')
});
```

$('mygrid').Grid()

Comment: `$left`? That's not a valid selector.. What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the formatting of your question, it's very hard to read.

If you want to select elements outside $(this), you can consider selecting them like you would normally do:

```
$("div.clickable").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $("div.outsidethis").doSomething();
});
```

Alternatively, you can use $.proxy() to pass the current context to your method:

```
$("div.clickable").click($.proxy(function(){
    // this is now NOT div.clickable but whatever this was before
}, this));
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Comment: Maybe he's not a native English speaker..

Comment: Yeah that worked. that was what I was after now i have to look up $.proxy. Sorry i tried to explain it well enough but you're the only one that got what i was trying to say thanks very much

Comment: No problem :) @Mr. Pallazzo, the problem wasn't about the English but about the formatting of the op's question (question/explanation/code run through each other)

Comment: aside from my presentation of my question the others didn't understand what i was saying and i got voted down that sucks. Glad you knew what i was trying to accomplish. I wanted to do it that way so i could keep bind events and trigger to my chained plugin

Comment: @KDM, excellent. You could also have used a more archaic method: var _this = this; $(..).click(function(){ _this.doSomething() });

Comment: I don't get what you're saying. I'm chaing my events and triggers how would that work the _this. update you're answer agin with code e.g